# Rating system javascript will not send results to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have what should be a functioning script, working to push ratings based on their value, i.e. 1/5, 2/5, 3/5 etc. But the script does not communicate with firebase at all. Is there a problem with my javascript, which would prevent the value of the input, to be sent to firebase as directed? Here is all of the necessary code. Also, there IS a link to firebase.js in the head of the document.

```js
(function() {
    var firebaseUrl = "https://myFirebase.firebaseIO.com/rating";
    var itemId = (rootRef).child;
    var rootRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);  // Reference the Firebase location
    var itemRef = rootRef.child("items").child(itemId);     //Define itemRef as the variable for itemId in firebase
    var star = $('.rating');
    var numRatings;
        star.click(function() {     //Watch out for rating1 inside of the website and grab its value. i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5
            itemRef.child("ratings").child("numRatings").set(star.val());   //Set ratings inside of Firebase with values such as 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, under items such as item1, item2, item3, etc... 
        });

    var cumulativeRating;
    var averageRating;
    itemRef.child("ratings").on("value", function(ratingsSnapshot) {
        var ratingsData = ratingsSnapshot.val();
        numRatings = ratingsData.numRatings;
        cumulativeRating = ratingsData.cumulativeRating;
        averageRating = cumulativeRating / numRatings;
    });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Rating system begin-->
    <div class="rating">
        <div class="starRating">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        <input id="rating1" class="rating" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
                        <label for="rating1"><span>1</span></label>
                        </div>
                    <input id="rating2" class="rating" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
                    <label for="rating2"><span>2</span></label>
                    </div>
                <input id="rating3" class="rating" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
                <label for="rating3"><span>3</span></label>
                </div>
            <input id="rating4" class="rating" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
            <label for="rating4"><span>4</span></label>
            </div>
        <input id="rating5" class="rating" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
        <label for="rating5"><span>5</span></label>
        </div>
                <h3 class="ratingtext">Rated 4/5 by 103 users</h3>   
                <!--Rating system end-->
```

Comment: You will have to learn how to debug your code, or you'll be here for every step. So if you [put a breakpoint on the line](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) that sets the value in Firebase (`itemRef.child("ratings")...`), does it get triggered?

Comment: What is `var itemId = (rootRef).child;` meant to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have quite a few small mistakes in your code. I will walk you through a few of them. But instead of just copying the code, please take time to understand how I actually figured these problems out. Your first goal should be to be able to debug your own code to get rid of these simpler mistakes.

OK, I will write up two problems. There might be more, but this already takes enough time.

1. handling the case where no data is in Firebase yet
2. getting the value of the clicked radio button

### handling the case where no data is in Firebase yet

The first thing that happened when I pasted your code into a jsbin is that it logs this to the JavaScript console in the devtools (you get these with <kbd>F12</kbd> and should **always** keep them open when developing):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numRatings' of null

This is modern JavaScript's version of a null pointer exception and is caused because you do `.numRatings` on something that is `null` or `undefined`. Lucky for me, you only have `.numRatings` in one place:

```
itemRef.child("ratings").on("value", function(ratingsSnapshot) {
    var ratingsData = ratingsSnapshot.val();
    numRatings = ratingsData.numRatings;
    cumulativeRating = ratingsData.cumulativeRating;
    averageRating = cumulativeRating / numRatings;
});
```

So it looks like `ratingsData` has no value, which indeed happens the first time when an item gets a rating. Firebase will trigger the `value` event with `null` (or `undefined`) in that case.

Handling it is easy:

```
itemRef.child("ratings").on("value", function(ratingsSnapshot) {
    var ratingsData = ratingsSnapshot.val();
    if (ratingsData) {
        numRatings = ratingsData.numRatings;
        cumulativeRating = ratingsData.cumulativeRating;
        averageRating = cumulativeRating / numRatings;
    }
});
```

In a real implementation you'll probably want to add an `else` to that `if` and show that there are no/not enough ratings yet.

### getting the value of the clicked radio button

You snippet for passing the clicked value to Firebase is:

```
var star = $('.rating');
star.click(function() {
    itemRef.child("ratings").child("numRatings").set(star.val());
});
```

The first thing I did is add a logging statement in there to see if the click is coming through to the code:

```
var star = $('.rating');
star.click(function() {
    console.log('click');
    itemRef.child("ratings").child("numRatings").set(star.val());
});
```

When I now click the radio button, it logs `click`. So it looks like that is wired up correctly. I often will put a [JavaScript `debugger` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) instead of the `console.log` as a next step, but decided against that this time around.

The next trick I did is setting up a simple Firebase logger to show whether the changes make it through to Firebase:

```
 new Firebase('https://you.firebaseIO.com/rating').on('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val())); })
```

You can add this anywhere to the top-level of your script. I most often add it to the console of my Chrome's devtools. Every time the value of your Firebase changes, it will log something like this:

```
{"items":{"42":{"ratings":{"numRatings":"3"}}}}
```

Or that's what it should do, but in your original script it never did. So we get inside the click handler, but the value doesn't make it to Firebase.

Closer inspection revealed something weird:

```
var star = $('.rating');
star.click(function() {
    itemRef.child("ratings").child("numRatings").set(star.val());
});
```

You use the variable `star` in the first line of this snippet to point to all rating elements. But then inside the click handler you do `star.val()`, which means you expect it to refer to a single rating element: the one that was clicked.

*A quick note on variables names here: you set yourself up for this mistake by using the singular `star` for the variable that contains all rating elements. I'd name that variable `stars`, to indicate that it contains multiple stars. That way you'd more easily see that something smells when you type `stars.val()`.*

I'm not a jQuery expert, but a quick Google of the [docs for jQuery's click method](http://devdocs.io/jquery/click) seem to indicate that you can access the clicked element as `this`. So the snippet needs to be:

```
var star = $('.rating');
star.click(function() {
    itemRef.child("ratings").child("numRatings").set($this).val());
});
```

And with that, my Firebase JSON logger started spewing out data:

```
{"items":{"42":{"ratings":{"numRatings":"3"}}}}
```

The values now make it to Firebase!

### Eliminate technologies from the problem

Note that this last change has nothing to do with Firebase. It would also have happened if you tried to alert the value:

```
var star = $('.rating');
star.click(function() {
    alert(star.val());
});
```

This is a key point when you are debugging a problem (or creating an MCVE): try to remove as many technologies from the problem as you can. By removing Firebase from this tiny code fragment, the problem went from "why doesn't my star rating make it into Firebase?" to "why doesn't this code fragment show the value of the star I clicked?" or once you get hang of it "how do I get the value of the element I clicked?". That last one is a question that you can type into Google and expect to get a decent result on, because you're not the first one to struggle with that. The pool of people trying to build a star rating system on Firebase is a lot smaller.

### Finally

As I said already, there are still things going wrong with your script. For example: every click on a radio button generates a pair of lines by my Firebase JSON logger:

```
{"items":{"42":{"ratings":{"numRatings":"3"}}}}
{"items":{"42":{"ratings":{"numRatings":""}}}}
```

So each time I click a radio button, it seems to trigger two changes in Firebase, with the second change undoing the work of the first change. I'm quite sure I can figure out why this happens. But I hope that with the lessons above, you will be able to figure this out on your own.

My final script:

```
(function() {
    var firebaseUrl = "https://your.firebaseio.com/rating";
    var itemId = 42; // TODO: look up Id of the actual item
    var rootRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);
    var itemRef = rootRef.child("items").child(itemId);
    var star = $('.rating');
    var numRatings;
    star.click(function() {
        itemRef.child("ratings").child("numRatings").set($(this).val());
    });

    var cumulativeRating;
    var averageRating;
    itemRef.child("ratings").on("value", function(ratingsSnapshot) {
        var ratingsData = ratingsSnapshot.val();
        if (ratingsData) {
            numRatings = ratingsData.numRatings;
            cumulativeRating = ratingsData.cumulativeRating;
            averageRating = cumulativeRating / numRatings;
        }
    });
})();
```

It's also up on jsbin, where I did my debugging: http://jsbin.com/lekifefuce/1/edit?js,output

Comment: What an incredible devotion of your time to my issue, I really do appreciate that! I was dumbfounded when I read your reveal on how to address the issue of 'star' with what should be 'stars'. It did not occur to me to use '$this' in my script, and although I know that I could have accomplished that fix, I am very appreciative that you did.

Comment: My knowledge of debugging does need practice, but in the use of alert (star.val()); such a method did in fact work for me, I got the value of each input when clicked, nevertheless, I am glad to find the working method for pushing results to firebase. As for the fix of adding to numRatings rather than replacing it, my first assumption is to change .set to .push with what little knowledge of firebase that I have. I will update my post with working alternatives to what I have. Thank you for your instruction, it really is a lesson, and not just a copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your security rules?

In firebase (link ref) go to Rules and add the array or object of interest (copy the example ovjects from a tutorial)

Eg set the read and write of rating to true